# rails undefined method view object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= debug(vote.song) %>
```

yields this:

```
--- !ruby/object:Song
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: Immigrant Song
  code: aiusbaina
  album: Led Zeppelin III
  created_at: 2012-09-08 10:02:51.654625000 Z
  updated_at: 2012-09-08 10:02:51.654625000 Z
```

why does this : <%= vote.song.name %> get an undefined method error (name) ?

Comment: should that work at all? do I have something wrong?

Comment: what variable are you looping to get `vote`?

Comment: Are you sure @votes contaains only valid data?